# After overriding some fonts, Document Viewer and others are not showing some texts

Tags: 10.10, fonts, pdf

After copying the fonts from my Windows XP system to the `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/` folder, the Document Viewer (version 2.23.0) is no more showing some texts (as the summary of my pdf). The same happens with Okular (version 4:4.5.5-0ubuntu2), ePDFViewer (version 0.1.7-4) and KPDF (3.5.10).

However, I could read my pdfs using xpdf (version 3.02-9) and Adobe Reader 9.

Any idea what went wrong with Document Viewer? I tried reinstalling it, but had no difference.

**--update:**

```
$ sudo fc-cache -v
/usr/share/fonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 3 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 6 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: skipping, existing cache is valid: 44 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/util: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: skipping, existing cache is valid: 272 fonts, 20 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont: skipping, existing cache is valid: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 60 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/takao: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/thai: skipping, existing cache is valid: 54 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu: skipping, existing cache is valid: 21 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-droid: skipping, existing cache is valid: 9 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-indic-fonts-core: skipping, existing cache is valid: 17 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-kacst-one: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-khmeros-core: skipping, existing cache is valid: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-lao: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-liberation: skipping, existing cache is valid: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-punjabi-fonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-symbol-replacement: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-symbol-replacement/symbol-replacement.ttf: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-ubuntu-title: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-xfree86-nonfree: skipping, existing cache is valid: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/umefont: skipping, existing cache is valid: 18 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/unfonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy: skipping, existing cache is valid: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1/mathml: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/local/share/fonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/home/tombrito/.fonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/home/tombrito/.fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
```

**--update:** Screenshots

The summary:

[image]

Comparison, Document Viewer on the left, and Adobe Reader on the right:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running an `fc-cache -v`? Does it produce any warnings?

Comment: @Pavlos G.: Looks like there's no errors, check out my update

Comment: Then how about trying an `fc-cache -f` in order to force the regeneration of the cache files...

Comment: @Pavlos G.: not.. also no error with -v -f

Comment: Maybe if were a cache problem it would be solved after a restart? Which is not the case.. So that might be some font missing or currupted in the truetype folder.. Is there some place where I can download the fonts again?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but i think that the font cache is not recreated after every restart.
As for the MS TTF fonts, try `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Comment: @tom - try moving `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` to a backup folder.  Rerun `fc-cache -f` - and then reinstall the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package that Pavlos G. has highlighted.

Comment: @Pavlos G.: Already did it, but nothing changed..

Comment: @fossfreedom also, nothing changed. As the it happens only with some pdf viewers, maybe I have to delete all files from this viewers and re-install them? (not sure if the Ubuntu Software Center's uninstall is removing all files..)

Comment: tom - you should be able to do this with something like `sudo apt-get purge <package name>`

Comment: @fossfreedom by the way, after moving the truetype folder, running `fc-cache -f` and reinstalling `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` I got `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: So, what is the current status of your machine?
Are you still at point zero?

Comment: Also, try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig`

Comment: @Pavlos G. Yes, I did the staff above, but I'm on the same state still. I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: @Pavlos G. The `sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig` run with no errors, but made no difference also.

Comment: The marked text in uour screenshot is supposed to be what font? what happens if you change it to some other?

Comment: I added a screenshot, the Summary is selectable, but not visible.

Comment: @TomBrito let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1002/discussion-between-pavlos-g-and-tom-brito)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove completely (don't just rename) the `truetype` folder from `/usr/share/fonts`.

Then do a `sudo fc-cache -f`
and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig`

Comment: Also, I need to reinstall some missing fonts now (that's why some programs are different), but this part is easy =)

Comment: The truetype folder was really not recreated, I think I'll try to copy it from my own ubuntu's system, in my house. But all fonts are showing correctly in the pdfs now.

Comment: I did an `apt-get remove` and an `apt-get install` with the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, and the truetype folder is there now. I wonder if this would solve all in the beggining (I never did the apt-get remove). Anyway, everything is ok now =)